# Nested attributes active record generating a "0" as a Hash key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

**Where is this "0" coming from in `owners_attributes`? Everything is working but this "0" key seems oddly out of place.. Is it normal/bug/or some setting? Leave it alone or remove it? Thanks!**

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "shorturl"=>{"redirect"=>"http://www.test.com",
                   "owners_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"email"=>"adm@test.com"}}}...
```

Strong_params:

```
def shorturl_params
  params.require(:shorturl).permit(:redirect, owners_attributes: [:email])
end
```

model:

```
class Shorturl < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :campaigns
  has_many :owners, through: :campaigns
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :owners
  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the internal format for how these are ported over via HTTP parameters. It allows multiple sets of nested attributes to be included.

It does look a little odd, but that shouldn't be a concern. The nested attribute handler will know what to do with it. It's only ever an issue if you need to manipulate these before they're intercepted by the default handler, but that's best avoided.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I try to do as much of my own "fishing" as possible. Could you share how you went about *discovering* this knowledge... Thanks again! @tadman

Comment: Probably the same way as you did, dealing with forms of this sort and paying close attention to the parameters. I make a habit of leaving `log/development.log` open with `tail -f` so I can see what Rails is doing as I load pages. It's the first place to go when something's not working right. The way the parameters are packaged up is pretty obvious if you're looking there.